# UrlGenerationError in Stores#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm running into what I think is a routing error. I was creating a shopping cart but somehow I'm missing the required key [:product_id]. I believe it may be beginners mistake not placing the right code somewhere.

No route matches {:action=>"add", :controller=>"carts", :product_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:product_id]

`app/views/stores/index.html.erb:34:in block in _app_views_stores_index_html_erb__2030225986820803304_70197415655620
app/views/stores/index.html.erb:3:in _app_views_stores_index_html_erb__2030225986820803304_70197415655620`

Carts_Controller.rb

```
 class CartsController < ApplicationController
 def show
   cart_ids = $redis.smembers current_user_cart
   @cart_products = Product.find(cart_ids)
 end

 def add
   $redis.sadd current_user_cart, params[:product_id]
   render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
 end

 def remove
   $redis.srem current_user_cart, params[:product_id]
   render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
 end

 private

 def current_user_cart
  "cart#{current_user.id}"
 end

 def carts_params
  params.require(:cart).permit(:product_id)
 end
end
```

Cart.rb

```
 class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
 end
```

Products_Controller.rb

```
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @products = Product.all
   @order_item = current_order.order_items.new
  end
 end
```

Routes.rb

```
  resource :cart, only: [:show] do
  put 'add/:product_id', to: 'carts#add', as: :add_to
  put 'remove/:product_id', to: 'carts#remove', as: :remove_from
  end
```

Stores/index.html

```
 <%=link_to "", class: "button", data: {target: @cart_action, addUrl: add_to_cart_path(@product_id), removeUrl: remove_from_cart_path(@product_id)} do%>
  <%=@cart_action%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing add_to_cart_path(@product_id) it sends the param as :id and you want it to be :product_id.

You can fix this two ways.

Way #1

In your button/link_to change

add_to_cart_path(@product_id)

to:

add_to_cart_path(product_id: @product_id)

Way #2

You can update your controller and route to expect and use the param id instead of product_id